# Cannot read source folder attempting to make any action

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, automated-tests, nightwatch.js

When attempting to run my nightwatch project with `npm run project_one`, I get this response.

```
There was an error while starting the test runner:

Error: Cannot read source folder: /Users/BenyJo/examples/tests
    at /Users/BenyJo/node_modules/nightwatch/lib/runner/run.js:203:21
    at /Users/BenyJo/node_modules/nightwatch/lib/runner/walk.js:97:18
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:21)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! package@1.0.0 project_one: `nightwatch`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the package@1.0.0 project_one script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Whenever I use any nightwatch command using npm, I get the same error, my Nightwatch config is as follows:

```
{
  "src_folders" : ["tests"],
  "output_folder" : "reports",

  "selenium" : {
    "start_process" : true,
    "server_path" : "./bin/selenium_v360.jar",
    "log_path" : "",
    "port" : 4444,
    "cli_args" : {
      "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "./bin/chromedriver"
    }
  },

  "test_settings" : {
    "default" : {
      "launch_url" : "http://localhost",
      "selenium_port"  : 4444,
      "selenium_host"  : "localhost",
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "acceptSslCerts": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

I've noticed that in that error, there is no file called, there should be a nightwatch folder in there. /Users/BenyJo/examples/tests

Comment: [Do not post images of code or errors!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same problem, there was a typo in my config file name. It must be named "nightwatch.json" (mine was named "nightwatch.js").

Answer (score 3):

`['nightwatch', '--', '--group', "$testSuite", '--env', "$projectEnv"]`.

I've resolved the issue **"Error: Cannot read source folder: /"**

Executing the command in this two ways:

```
nightwatch -- --group testSuite --env nameEnv
npm run test -- --group testSuite --env nameEnv


nightwatch -- --test testsFile/testSuite --env default

npm run test -- --test testsFile/testSuite --env default
```

Keep in mind the double argument lines: "-- --group".

It resolved `runner.js` in this way to Nightwatch execution

you can Replace the group or file test in your project and review the test Setting in `nighwatch.json` to resolve the parameter `--env` or `-e`